# Using Atlas ui components without a Layer client

Tags: android, atlas

I've been looking at the atlas ui messaging components for android. I'm confused about one thing that is not clear in the documentation. To use atlas ui components on Android, does one have to have a Layer client or is it possible to use your own backend and get message data to add to the components. The documentation is not clear on this and I hope someone can shed some light. Thanks.

Comment: Turns out you cannot use the library without a layer client. A real big shame